# Ubuntu preseed. Use whole disk space, but no swap

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, preseed

I'm trying to make a installation usb stick for a equipment we have here. I would like to automate linux installation, because we have a lot of these machines to install.

The machine has a 30GB SSD .  I want preseed to use the entire disk to create an ext4 partition (mount point '/') and do not create a swap (it's a SSD, so no swap to avoid more read/write).

I read some blog's and articles on the internet where you define an expert_recipe to partman. But I wasn't able to find and option to say use the whole free space. There's the defaut option for partman but I believe (not sure of that) partman would create a swap partition.

How could I do that? Tell preseed to create a single partition using the entire disk and not create a swap partition ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`partman` indeed creates swap partitions by default, unless you use the expert option.
The following expert_recipe creates a single root partition for the entire disk.

```
d-i partman-basicfilesystems/no_swap boolean false
d-i partman-auto/expert_recipe string myroot :: 1000 50 -1 ext4 \
     $primary{ } $bootable{ } method{ format } \
     format{ } use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 } \
     mountpoint{ / } \
    .
d-i partman-auto/choose_recipe select myroot
```

Line 1 disables the `partman` warning about a missing swap partition.
Lines 2-6 create a single partition with a minimum size of 1000 MB. The `-1` indicates the maximum size (infinite), which makes `partman` grow the partition to the size of the disk.